PHPMailer getOAuth2token response to div
Is there a way to redirect the output of PHPMailer's get_oauth_token.php (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/get_oauth_token.php) into an adot div? I pasted the file from github into an mvc-based program that is being prepared.
The script runs nicely, then when the header( 'Location: ' . $authUrl ); reaches line, refreshes the whole page:
localhost/Admin/getOAuth2Token?state=...
Or when you are redirected to Google's page on the first invitation, due to connecting and enabling the program to your account.
I would like to load this into a specified div, if possible, so that I can stay within the page.

You'd have to fundamentally rewrite the whole thing to function as an API responding to an AJAX request from the browser, I think. I don't know if the auth providers would necessarily work well with that scenario though - usually the provider pages will want to post back to their own servers, which might not work very well. Most of the big providers such as Google have their own JS libraries for doing client-side auth which is designed for more of a single-page app scenario. The example in that script is more for server-side auth flows I think.

It's worth reading a guide such as https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2 to understand the different scenarios and flows available with such oauth2 providers.

This is a redirect back to your site, so you can not have that "stay within the same page."
You could try and open the auth URL in a popup though; and then, when the user has been redirected back to your redirect_uri within the popup, you can have the popup communicate with the opening window using postMessage, and then close the popup. (Assuming you still get access to window.opener after the redirect back, not sure, you'd have to test that. But f.e. Facebook manages to implement the same process for their client-side login flow, so it should be possible.)

yes that worked... :) ajax handles the form and then
success: function ( response ) { popupWindow = window.open( response, "", "width=300,height=300" ); }
Thank you very much!
